# Suspension when closing the lid does not work

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop

I have an Asus Zenbook 14 Oled with Ubuntu 23.10. When I close the lid, the laptop doesn't suspend.

I have already edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncommenting:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
```

I have also tried using Gnome Tweaks and changing the option *'Suspend when laptop lid is closed'*.

I tried to check lid state using `cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state` and it correctly detects opening and closing.

Suspending the laptop manually works.